# Add a .svg picture to a slide

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I code a PowerPoint addin where I need to add a picture to the current slide. The picture is stored in Resources in .svg format.

I can add a picture in any format to a slide if this picture is stored **locally** and not in Resources with:

```
mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\...", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 50, 50);
```

I can add a picture in **png or jpg** stored in Resources using clipboard

```
Clipboard.SetImage(MyApp.Properties.Resources.myImage);
mySlide.Shape.Paste();
```

But I can't **add a .svg stored in Resources**. Do you have an idea of how to add to the PowerPoint slide a .svg stored in Resource - without copying the image locally and importing it with the first method) ?
For example do you know if there is a function like

```
mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture(---goToThisResourcesFilInsteadOfALocalPath---, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 50, 50); ?
```

Comment: AFAIK the PowerPoint Interop API doesn't provide any methods that allow adding images from a stream, therefor you'll have to create a temporary / local file that you can then add to the PowerPoint slide. An other alternative would be looking into other libraries that directly work on PPTX files (for example like OpenXML or something similar).

Comment: Which version of PowerPoint is in question, here? Support in Office for the *.svg file format is quite recent and is, I believe, only available in Office 365 (subscription version, not the *.msi install version).

Comment: @ Cindy Mesiter. It is PowerPoint 2016 not online version